# nodemodule not found file or directory

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

When I remove some extra files in my project i found an error. It create a much of errors
in my project

**Following picture is showing as**
[image]

I did't have any idea to solve it help me to solve the issue.

Comment: The file that is listed should be available at specified path. If it really is, then this is a problem in compiler, it needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

You removed the file "CustomerList.vue" but you are importing it from another place. Just remove the import.

Comment: You are welcome. If that answers your question, you can mark it as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete **node-modules** folder.
2. run command `npm cache clean --force`.
3. run command `npm install`.
4. Finally install the package again with `npm install your-package-name`.

Comment: I try it but it did'n work.Something new happens to do that.

Comment: can you please show me the package.json file? and What do you mean by something new happens?

Comment: This answer is wrong. It would work if a node dependency was missing. But in this case, the build fails because a source file (CustomerList.vue) is missing.